# Seeing if object exists in S3 using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am using PHP and I am using the S3 API to upload a file, but I wanted to make sure that this exact filename doesn't already exist in the bucket before upload.

I have found a few examples online that use "file_get_contents" but doesn't this mean that you would have to download the entire file first? Usually, these files are about 10 mb, so ideally, I wouldn't really want to do this.

Is there perhaps a way to use "file_get_contents" without downloading the file?

Or better yet, perhaps I could use an API request to see if the filename exists?

It's not important to me whether or not the content, or filesize, is the same, just the filename.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Gets whether or not the specified Amazon S3 object exists in the specified bucket.

[AmazonS3 `doesObjectExist`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.S3.S3ClientInterface.html#_doesObjectExist)

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$bucket = 'my-bucket' . strtolower($s3->key);

$response = $s3->doesObjectExist($bucket, 'test1.txt');

// Success? (Boolean, not a CFResponse object)
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: This link and method are for version 1 of the AWS SDK for PHP. The updated user guide is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/index.html and the relevant section for checking a file's existence is using the stream wrapper, found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html

Comment: the link to the updated docs, to the exact method is: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_doesObjectExist

Comment: The correct function to use should be `$s3->doesObjectExist(...)`

Comment: @BrianLeishman thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I'm using this function,since its too slow to return the value,need to wait so long! is there any way to get the response quickly?

Comment: Link to v3 docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.S3.S3ClientInterface.html#_doesObjectExist

Comment: Now in 2023,  doesObjectExist() appears to have been deprecated in favor of  doesObjectExistV2() : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.S3.S3ClientInterface.html#_doesObjectExistV2

Answer (score 12):

try to use code below:

```
$s3 = new S3();

$info = $s3->getObjectInfo($bucket, $filename);
if ($info)
{
    echo 'File exists';
}
else
{
    echo 'File does not exists';
}
```

download the S3 SDK from amazon for php. There is a class called S3; create an object of S3. The object will allow to call the getObjectInfo() method. Pass your S3 bucket name and the file name (often the file name is referred as key). The getObjectInfo() method will return some information if the file exists, otherwise the method will return FALSE.

Comment: A little explanation would improve this answer a lot. It's currently in the "low quality" review queue, probably because it consists mostly of code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just explained the code.

Comment: This should be the ticked answer. Simplest and the best.

Comment: Hi i have question, Is the above method is Good or PHP's @getimagesize($filename)) is Good? 

Above code will go as a GET request only right?
But Php's getimagesize will eat bandwidth and GET request both right?

Comment: I added file name as a second parameter but it shows Message: S3::getObjectInfo(portal-static-assets, x1.xls): [403] Unexpected HTTP status

Comment: Please pass the file name as string 'x1.xls', see if that helps

Answer (score 8):

Please note that the other suggestions are based on version 1 of the AWS SDK for PHP. For version 2, you'll want to be familiar with the latest guide found here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/index.html

The "Getting Started" section in the link above will help you get the SDK installed and setup, so be sure to take your time reading through those docs if you haven't done so already. When you're done with the setup, you'll want to be familiar with the stream wrapper method found here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html

Finally, below is a brief, real-life example of how you could use it in the flow of your code.

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');

// your filename
$filename = 'my_file_01.jpg';
// this will use AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY from env vars
$s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory();
// S3_BUCKET must also be defined in env vars
$bucket = getenv('S3_BUCKET')?: die('No "S3_BUCKET" config var in found in env!');
// register stream wrapper method
$s3->registerStreamWrapper();
// does file exist
$keyExists = file_exists("s3://".$bucket."/".$filename);
if ($keyExists) {
    echo 'File exists!';
}
```

Comment: using v2 and $s3->registerStreamWrapper(), the file_exists("s3://".$bucket."/".$filename) gets me a "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Aws\S3\Exception\NoSuchKeyException: AWS Error Code: NoSuchKey, Status Code: 404" rather than a nice true or false. Seem's I need to catch that exception :(

Answer (score 5):

Updated version for anyone looking for v3 and up...

```
$s3Client = new \Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => getenv('AWS_REGION'),
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => getenv('AWS_KEY'),
        'secret' => getenv('AWS_SECRET')
    ]
]);
$response = $s3Client->doesObjectExist(getenv('AWS_S3_BUCKET'),'somefolder/somefile.ext');
if ($response) {
    echo "Yay, it exists :)";
} else {
    echo "Boo, nothing there :(";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have or have the ability to install the PECL extension [HTTP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php) then you can use [http_head](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-head.php) to make a head request easily and check whether the response was 200 or 404.